# Testing java FXML

Tags: java

I'm using scene builder and making an interface to register a new user to my application. For the user to chose an age, I have implemented a "slider"-object I have named ageSlider. Next to the slider-object, I have a "label"-object named ageDisplay, which shows the current position of the "thumb" of the slider. The displayAge()-method below is called from the slider whenever a drag motion is detected:

```
public void displayAge() {
    double ageNumber = ageSlider.getValue();
    int age = (int) Math.ceil(ageNumber);
    ageDisplay.setText(age+""); 
}
```

It all works perfectly fine when I open it as a Java application and test it manually. My problem is when I want to test that this works by using code:

```
@Test
public void testAgeSlider() {
    Label ageDisplay = lookup("#ageDisplay").query();
    Slider ageSlider = lookup("#ageSlider").query();
    /*somehow simulate a user who drags the thumb of the ageSlider to 
    the value 50 for example*/
    assertEquals("50", ageDisplay.getText());   
}
```

Hope someone can help me!

Answer (score 0):

Change your testAgeSlider method to :

```
@Test
public void testAgeSlider() {
    Label ageDisplay = (Label) this.getScene().lookup("#ageDisplay");
    Slider ageSlider = (Slider) this.getScene().lookup("#ageSlider");
    /*somehow simulate a user who drags the thumb of the ageSlider to 
    the value 50 for example*/
    assertEquals("50", ageDisplay.getText());   
}
```

Where ***this*** is a component from your current fxml controller

Comment: The problem is not in the lookup-method. I want to find a way to simulate a user dragging the thumb of the ageSlider to a specific value!